# How to write a try catch statement where I need to check two things

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a method which have a try catch clause where I parse a mobile phone number.
If parsing goes OK, the code outside the try continues to execute.
If parsing encounters an error, I enter the catch and raise the error.

All this was OK until I got a request to check for another phone number.

I am not sure how to do it because later in the code **I need at least one correct phone number (its not important which one)**.

If I put both parsing inside one try, I have a problem if first one is wrong and second is good because exception will be raised anyway.

```
try {
    model.mobilePhone = PhoneParser.Parse(m.mobile);
    model.alternativePhoneNumber = PhoneParser.Parse(m.alternativePhoneNumber);
}

catch (Exception) {
    _log.LogWarning("Error while parsing the phone number")
}

return model;
```

Maybe something like this? Try inside a catch?

```
try {
    model.mobilePhone = PhoneParser.Parse(m.mobile);
}

catch (Exception) {
    try {
         model.alternativePhoneNumber = PhoneParser.Parse(m.alternativePhoneNumber);
  }
     catch (Exception) {
         _log.LogWarning("Error while parsing the alternative phone number")
  }
    _log.LogWarning("Error while parsing the mobile phone number")
}

return model;
```

Comment: Do you have access to the `PhoneParser.Parse` method? If so, why not change it to be more like `int.TryParse`?

Comment: Why do these operations need to be combined at all?  If the try/catch structure for parsing one value was working, why not just repeat that same structure for the second value?

Comment: Two David's, nice :) for DavidG, I do have access, but inside it have several checks which are raising the exceptions, like if (phoneNumber.Length < 9) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid phone number"); if (phoneNumber == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(); if (phoneNumber.Length > 15)
                throw new OverflowException("Phone number with calling code cannot have more than 15 characters");

Comment: @David, you mean try {
    model.mobilePhone = PhoneParser.Parse(m.mobile);
}
catch (Exception) {
    _log.LogWarning("Error while parsing the phone number")
}
try {
    model.alternativePhoneNumber = PhoneParser.Parse(m.alternativePhoneNumber);
}

catch (Exception) {
    _log.LogWarning("Error while parsing the phone number")
}

Comment: @sosNiLa: Yes.  Unless parsing the second value somehow *depends upon* the result of parsing the first value, I don't see why they need to be mashed together at all.

Comment: @sosNiLa if you were to use the int.tryparse you will be able to null check the out value

Comment: I forgot to mention its a string, not an int...

Comment: Since a phonenumber could start with a zero you could never int.parse it without losing a leading zero. Do you really wish to parse the string to int? Couldn't you implement regex to validate the phonenumber instead?

Comment: The question is, what if the format of `m.mobile` is wrong. Is this field optional? Are you able to continue to the `alternativePhoneNumber`? Don't nest try/catch, use two different blocks.

Comment: @Roe, it has to be a string because inside the same PhoneParser.Parse method, I am adding the country code.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, yes, I need at least one number to be correct.

Comment: I would create a separate function which does the `TryParse()`

Comment: @Roe It should be self-evident that a phone number is not being stored as an `int`. Even if stored without separators (`.`, `-`, or `()`, you would only allow for ~25% of all possible phone numbers, and then only if you are using a 10-digit phone number like in the US without a country code at the beginning. If not constrained to that, then it's limited to significantly less than 25% of all possible numbers.

Comment: If you own the code of your phone number parser, **please don't throw** `OverflowException` in this case. This exception class has a [very specific meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=net-7.0) in c#, regarding arithmetic overflow in checked code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is to have two separate `try/catch` blocks. Otherwise, the alternate phone number will only ever get added if the primary phone number fails (but it's likely that if they supplied both, both are valid).

```
try 
{
    model.mobilePhone = PhoneParser.Parse(m.mobile);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.LogWarning($"Error while parsing the mobile phone number:\r\n{e}")
}

try 
{
    model.alternativePhoneNumber = PhoneParser.Parse(m.alternativePhoneNumber);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    _log.LogWarning($"Error while parsing the alternative phone number:\r\n{e}")
}

return model;
```

As others have suggested, implementing a `TryParse` might be helpful, but then you'll lose the exception information that you're currently logging now. Also, the `TryParse` should not wrap calls to `Parse` in `try/catch` blocks, because exception handling is expensive. Instead it should use the same logic as the `Parse` method, but return `false` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I advise against nesting try-catches.

Use two separate try-catches for each field (`model.PhoneNumber` and `model.AlternativePhoneNumber`).

Although the best way of solving your issue would be creating a separate `.TryParse()` extension method for phone number and using that. This would also conform your code to DRY (do not repeat yourself) principle.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is one valid phone number, create a little helper method in your model called `EnsureValidState`

```
public void EnsureValidState()
{
   if(this.mobilePhone == null && this.alternativePhoneNumber ==null) 
   {
     //no valid state, raise exception
   }
    
    //other validation for different rules.
}
```

Call this method, after all your properties are set and validate accordingly.
You could even abstract this away into an abstract base class for your entities:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
   private abstract void EnsureValidState();
}
```

If you want to go a step further have a look at the Hands on DDD example code over at https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Domain-Driven-Design-with-.NET-Core/blob/086cabf75211daa8df9d2117dec0181a0339749d/Marketplace.Framework/Entity.cs, that will give you an idea on how to implement a more generic way to ensure consistent updates on your entites and models.